# Execute a function after a variable is updated

Tags: javascript

I'm writing modular JavaScript and I have a certain function that does a whole lotta processing, viz. Draw 2 canvases, update a lot of variables and store object references. Now I want to execute another function which uses some of the variables updated above.

Something like this:

- Paint canvases - Store image dimensions in variables (and a lot of other stuff)
- Use those dimensions to do some math and geometry, update the canvases again! I can't do this math in the first function, as it is a common utility function I use to paint canvas, everywhere in my code.

If I inject a `setTimeout` in my code for 10 seconds, everything works fine, but without it, the second instruction above does not find the updated variables and hence fails.

Any way to work around this? Meaning, I want to execute the second instruction ONLY after some of the required variables are set. Synchronous execution, I say.

Note: I can't post any code here (or anywhere for that matter) as it is not allowed in my workplace!

Comment: How can you use "modular JavaScript" and "lot of Globals" in one sentence? :-)

Comment: You caught me! ;) I mean some values which are stored as a property. Updating the description...

Comment: You could use `window.postMessage` and `window.addEventListener("message"...` to Notify your program to execute a specific task.

Answer (score 2):

For cases like this, I suggest to use [jQuery and custom events](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). Simply post an event when the first function has finished updating the canvas. The second function (and anything else) can listen to these events and do whatever they want.

Pro:

- No coupling
- Individual parts are easy to test
- Extensible

Con:

- Needs jQuery or you'll need to extract the event handling code.

Comment: You mean trigger when done?
(I am using jQuery for 80% of the work!)

Comment: Yes. That way, any number of independent listeners can do something.

Answer (score 1):

You could use getters and setters to watch for you for a given condition.
In the setter you can do some computations,  check if some conditions are met
 and update if required.

Just to give you an idea :

```
 // updateFunc is the function called whenever a property changes
 // and all conditions are met for an update.
 // newProp1,2,3 are the new values for prop1,2,3
 function MyStorageClass(updateFunc, newProp1, newProp2, newProp3 ) {
    this.updateFunc = updateFunc;
    this.prop1 = newProp1 ;
    this.prop2 = newProp2 ;
    this.prop3 = newProp3 ;
 }

 var MSCProto = MyStorageClass.prototype;

 // update is needed if all properties are >0
 MSCProto.checkUpdateRequired = function() {
   return ( ( this.prop1 > 0 ) && (this.prop2 > 0) && (this.prop3 > 0) )
 }

 Object.defineProperty(MSCProto, 'prop1', {  
        get : function() { retrurn this._prop1},
        set : function(x) { this._prop1 = x;  
                            // and some other computations if need be
                            if (this.checkUpdateRequired()) this.updateFunc(); } };

 Object.defineProperty(MSCProto, 'prop2', {  
        get : function() { retrurn this._prop2},
        set : function(x) { this._prop2 = x;  
                            // and some other computations if need be
                            if (this.checkUpdateRequired()) this.updateFunc(); } };      

 Object.defineProperty(MSCProto, 'prop3', {  
        get : function() { retrurn this._prop3},
        set : function(x) { this._prop3 = x;  
                            // and some other computations if need be
                            if (this.checkUpdateRequired()) this.updateFunc(); } };
```